# Disabling default sails.js routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm setting up a basic Sails.js app, and I'm trying to disable the default routing system in sails.js. The documentation [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.blueprints.html) seems to indicate it can be disabled in the `/config/blueprints.js` file, by setting `module.exports.blueprints = { actions: false };`

However, when I do `sails lift`, I'm still able to access my default controller at `/foo`

Edit: This is using Sails v0.10.5, with no changes other than the two files below.

```
/**   /api/controllers/FooController.js **/
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        return res.send("blah blah blah");
    }
};

/**   /config/blueprints.js **/
module.exports.blueprints = {
    actions: false,
    rest: false,
    shortcuts: false,
    prefix: '',
    pluralize: false,
    populate: false,
    autoWatch: true,
    defaultLimit: 30
};
```

Additionally, the issue continues to occur if I disable blueprints on a per-controller basis:

```
/**   /api/controllers/FooController.js **/
module.exports = {
    _config: { actions: false, shortcuts: false, rest: false },
    index: function(req, res) {
        return res.send("blah blah blah");
    }
};
```

The controller is still accessible at `/foo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is a little bit tricky. You are trying to open Controller.index method.
At the same time you are disabled routing for all actions.

But actually Sails.js in 0.10.5 has additional configuration that disables index route from controller.
Its name: index.

So you disabled auto routing for all actions except index..

To disable all auto routes you have to set:

```
_config: {
    actions: false,
    shortcuts: false,
    rest: false,

    index: false
}
```

Seems that somebody just forgot to add this into docs.

Comment: That's it! It also seems to work on a global level, from the `/config/blueprints.js` file as well.

Comment: Thanks, wish this was in the documentation!

Comment: No need to add `index : false` now, it works without it. That applies globally and controller specific configurations

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using policies under the **config** folder.

```
module.exports.policies = {
    YourControllerName: {
        'find': true,
        '*': false
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly, but what if I want to expose a controller through a different (custom) route? i.e. I want FooController to be accessible through /foostuff, but _not_ /foo?

Comment: you can do it by using `/config/route.js` see the documentation [link](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

To disable the default rest routes generated for models you should set `rest: false`
in file `/config/blueprints.js`

> This solution is for sails V1.x

```
  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Automatically expose RESTful routes for your models?                     *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  rest: false,
```